# How to show validation message after radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation, radio-button

I have two inline radio button in a form using Bootstrap. But when I validate it then the message showing inside of first radio button instead of showing after second radio button. I would like to show that radio button message like Email and password. Here is the screenshot of my form.

Without Validation:[image]

With Validation:
[image]

HTML Form:

```
<form name="registration" action="">
        <div class="signingInner"> 
          <h4 style="font-weight: 500;  text-align:center; font-size: 20px ">Sign in to your Account</h4>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="emailId">Email Address:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login_email" name="login_email" placeholder="Please enter Email address">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login_password" id="login_password" placeholder="&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <div class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 100px;">
                  <input type="radio" id="user" name="LoginMode" value="user" >
                  As <strong>User</strong> </>
              </div>
              <div class="radio-inline" style="padding-left: 30px;">
                  <input type="radio" id="company" name="LoginMode" value="company" >
                  As <strong>Company</strong></>
              </div>
          </div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Login"></input>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Plunker Link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0vpvU9QbRu8Mlwbi04ti?p=preview

Comment: I am not a good designer but i think you should keep a common div over radio button section and then show the error there instead of showing to only one section. Since the message suggests to select any one of the below.
Also you can highlight the whole form group if you want to highlight the section.

Comment: Can you make a plunkr link?

Comment: @Neel, Please check. I have added Plunker link at below of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `errorPlacement` callback function.

So I am checking whether the rendered type is radio button then I am tracking the appropriate topmost parent div and inserting the message after that.

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if ( element.is(":radio") ) {                   
            error.insertAfter( element.parent().parent().parent().parent());
        }
        else { // This is the default behavior of the script for all fields
            error.insertAfter( element );
        }
 },
```

See the updated <kbd>[plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/MGMW0PpXZ3DIxjX3rTuK?p=preview)</kbd>.

And the output looks like [image]

EDIT:

I have finally updated the [**original plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/6xYi4kUeRFoKAdRywff4?p=preview) provided by you.

Comment: Thanks @Neel. Let me try in my login form.

Comment: @Neel, I saw that this is with Bootstrap 3.0.3. Bootstrap 4.1.3 has a built in validation tool:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#validation but is a bit finicky with horizontal radio buttons. How would you make this solution work for Bootstrap 4.1.3? Thanks!